# Why is webservice call returning false?

Tags: php, web-services, curl, get

In order to receive information from a webservice I'm doing:

```
$url = "http://webserviceurl.com/index.php?param1=1&param2=2"; 
//url tested, it's returning data when pasted in a browser
$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$info = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
echo $info ;
```

phpinfo() says curl is enabled

But $info is returning a FALSE, when I was expecting the information I asked to the webservice through the parameters in the url

Can anybody, please, give me a clue on what is wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Your call is failing. What do you see if you add `var_dump(curl_error($c));` right after the `curl_exec()` call?

Comment: string(20) "connect() timed out!"

Comment: Well there is your answer.  The remote server is not getting a connection within your specified timeout. You should a) verify the endpoint is correct b)  verify your server is able to connect to that endpoint.  By the way, it is always best for your code to handle all possible responses, including failures, so that your code can log errors and such as necessary, If you had done this initially, you could have saved yourself however much time you spend troubleshooting to this point and posting question. waiting for answer and already be on to investigating the connection problem.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but the url is returning data when pasted in a browser .. so I guess the endpoint is correct, am I right? And can you please tell how I can verify if my server can connect to that endpoint?

Comment: You could run a ping, traceroute, dns lookup, etc. from your server to help troubleshoot the problem.